# How to set Value for Java compiler in WebSphere application server

Tags: jvm, websphere, jit

How to set Java Compiler from NONE to J9JIT27 or J9JIT26for any JVM in WebSphere Console

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere Application Server by default IS using JIT. You can disable it if you want for example via console - `Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual machine > Disable JIT` - see [Java virtual machine settings](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rconfproc_jvm.html) for more details

Looking at the [JIT FAQ](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/understanding/jit_faq.html) it is not possible to change JIT version:

> **Can I use any version of the JIT compiler with the JVM?**
>
> No. The two are tightly coupled. You must use the version of the JIT compiler that comes with the JVM package that you use.